# Solving issues of resSystem.HttpResponse[Status=Method Not Allowed, StatusCode=405]

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, apexrest, http

Iam trying to use rest to retrive the files from one org to another org

1.To send the Id of the content version in opportunity from source org to target org
2.Target Org should get the id and store the file in the org and return the url of the particular file to the target org
3.source org should get the url and save the url in the customfield.

Source org

```
public class GetAccountUsingRESTAPI {
    private final String clientId = 'clientid';
    private final String clientSecret = 'clientsecret';
    private final String username = 'uisername';
    private final String password = 'Password securityToken';
    public class deserializeResponse
    {
        public String id;
        public String access_token;
    }
    public String ReturnAccessToken (GetAccountUsingRESTAPI acount)
    {
        String reqbody = 'grant_type=password' + '&client_id='+clientId +
        '&client_secret='+clientSecret + '&username='+username + '&password='+password;
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setBody(reqbody);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        deserializeResponse response = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
        system.debug('@@@@access_token@@'+response );
        return response.access_token;
    }
    public static void callGetAccount()
    {
        GetAccountUsingRESTAPI acount1 = new GetAccountUsingRESTAPI();
        String accessToken;
        accessToken = acount1.ReturnAccessToken (acount1);
     //   list<ContentVersion> ListAccount=new List<ContentVersion>();
        ContentVersion conDoc =  [SELECT Id, Title, VersionData FROM ContentVersion where ID= '0684W00000EWbOLQA1'];
        system.debug('conDoc==='+conDoc);
        //get ContentVersion body
        String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(conDoc.VersionData);
        Id accID = '0064W0000147uctQAA';    
        
        if(accessToken != null) {
            if(accessToken != Null){
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            string Endpoint = ('https://sls-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/');
            system.debug('endPoint'+Endpoint);
            req.setMethod('POST');
            system.debug('bodyEncoded===='+bodyEncoded);
            req.setBody('');
            req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '  +accessToken);
            req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            //req.setHeader('accept','application/json');
                        req.setEndpoint(endPoint);
            System.debug('END-POINT===='+req.getEndpoint());
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);            
            system.debug('res'+res);
            }
         }}
}
```

Target Org

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/opportunity/*')
global with sharing class ShareFileRest {

    @HttpGet
    global static String getFileToStore() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    String ContentDocumentId= RestContext.request.params.get('accID') ;
    String name= RestContext.request.params.get('Title') ;
  //insert contentVersion
        contentVersion cVersion = new contentVersion();
        cVersion.PathOnClient =name;
        cVersion.title =name;
        cVersion.versionData = req.requestBody;
        insert cVersion;        
        ID conDocument = [Select ContentDocumentID from ContentVersion where ID=:cVersion.ID].ContentDocumentID;
        //insert ContentDocumentLink
        ContentDocumentLink conDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
        conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = ContentDocumentId;
        conDocLink.ContentDocumentId = conDocument;
        insert conDocLink;  
        RestContext.response.addHeader('content-Type','application/json');
        //RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(generateJSON('SUCCESS', conDocument,'' )); 
        String url = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toexternalForm(); //Returns a string representation of the current URL.
        String downUrl= url.substring(0,url.indexOf('.lightning.force.com')); //  - It is use for get index of string/character from the specified from index.
        return (downUrl +'/lightning/r/Opportunity/'+cVersion.Id+'/view ');     
    } 
}
```

ERROR

While sending the request I get the status 405 error

```
resSystem.HttpResponse[Status=Method Not Allowed, StatusCode=405]
```

[image]

Comment: I notice that you set your methods in your requests to 'POST' but your target org's endpoint is defined as @HttpGet.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting the wrong endpoint.

```
string Endpoint = ('https://sls-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/');
```

That's the [Resources by Version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_discoveryresource.htm) endpoint, which you cannot `POST` to.

You need to be using the endpoint in your target org for your custom Apex REST endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,Is that I have to  set the endpoint in my target org